# Multiplicity constraint violated when trying to clone Entity Framework object

Tags: c#, entity-framework, orm, clone

I am trying to duplicate an object in Entity Framework using the method in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15322430/817630), but when I call `Add(clone)` I get an InvalidOperationException saying that a multiplicity constraint has been violated. My code looks like this

```
var dbSet = context.Set<MyObject>()
var clone = dbSet.Include(e => e.Property1)
                 .Include(e => e.Property2)
                 .Include(e => e.Property3)
                 .AsNoTracking()
                 .First(e => e.Id == OriginalPrimaryKey)
dbSet.Add(clone); // Throws InvalidOperationException
context.SaveChanges();
```

The stack trace looks like

> System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
>   HResult=-2146233079   Message=Multiplicity constraint violated. The
>   role 'MyObject_Property1_Target' of the relationship
>   'DataModels.MyObject_Property1' has
>   multiplicity 1 or 0..1.   Source=EntityFramework   StackTrace:
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.EntityEntry.WillNotRefSteal(EntityReference
>   refToPrincipal, IEntityWrapper wrappedPrincipal)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.EntityEntry.FixupEntityReferenceToPrincipal(EntityReference
>   relatedEnd, EntityKey foreignKey, Boolean setIsLoaded, Boolean
>   replaceExistingRef)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.EntityEntry.FixupReferencesByForeignKeys(Boolean
>   replaceAddedRefs, EntitySetBase restrictTo)
>          at

Note that `Property1` is a full object with a foreign key back to `MyObject`. From what I can tell, the multiplicity error is coming from the fact that the `Property1` objects between an existing entity and my clone are "the same" according to EF (they are not reference equal, I checked).

From the looks of the above answer, I thought when using `AsNoTracking` EF would handle this and generate a new version of the `Property1` entity to save to the database. Is this not the case? If not, what is the best way to clone my entire entity with all referenced properties?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I fixed this by setting the primary keys of all referenced properties to 0. So my code now looks like

```
var dbSet = context.Set<MyObject>();
var clone = dbSet.Include(e => e.Property1)
                 .Include(e => e.Property2)
                 .Include(e => e.Property3)
                 .AsNoTracking()
                 .First(e => e.Id == OriginalPrimaryKey);
clone.Property1.Id = 0;
clone.Property2.Id = 0;
clone.Property3.Id = 0;
dbSet.Add(clone);
context.SaveChanges();
```

I'm not sure if this is the right way to do this—it certainly doesn't feel right—but I haven't been able to find anything else that works.

Comment: I don't know if it is right either, but it fixed my problem so thanks.

Comment: I had a piece of code that worked for years but suddenly threw this error. Also feels wrong but I did this method and it solved my issue (only needed to nil a special 1  0..1 relation.