# EF Update table

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a table in Code First in Entity Framework

```
public class Foo
{
    public string A;
    public string B;
}
```

I am trying to update table Foo in the database

```
Foo foo2 = new Foo
{
    A = "a",
    B = "b"
};

Foo foo1= db.Foo.Find(1);
foo1 = foo2;
```

and i know `foo1 = foo2` wont work because EF will track the reference of  `foo1` and with
`foo1 = foo2` `foo1` will get the reference of `foo2` and update works if i assign new value to the object one by one

```
foo1.A = foo2.A;
foo1.B = foo2.B
```

but is there any way I can achieve this just by copying the data from one object to second? Thanks

so far I have tried this: [Shallow Copy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.memberwiseclone(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
public Foo Clone()
{
    return (Foo)this.MemberwiseClone();
}
```

but still

```
foo1 = foo2.Clone();
```

is not working

Comment: You can find original reference of Foo by key value of your foo2 reference. like db.Foo.First(a=>a.A = foo2.A) and then update this first reference by foo2 and say update actual instance

Comment: or `db.Foo.Update(foo1)` should work if your `Foo` is part of entity class.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for **deep copy/cloning**.
To solve your problem you could implement you way of `deep copying/cloning` your objects.
See details here: [Deep cloning objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/deep-cloning-objects)

Or as a simple EF solution you could get out the properties from the object with `AsNoTracking()` ans set them to a new object. Example:

```
var originalEntity = Context.MySet.AsNoTracking()
                             .FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == 1);
Context.MySet.Add(originalEntity);
Context.SaveChanges();
```

Explanation here: [Entity Framework 5 deep copy/clone of an entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15308747/entity-framework-5-deep-copy-clone-of-an-entity)