# Insert record in database from template record without altering template - Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to insert a record into my database based on an existing record which functions as template using Entity Framework.

The flow right now is:

```
var newModel = organization.Models.Where(m => m.IsTemplate == true).FirstOrDefault();

newModel.Name = "Something New";
newModel.IsTemplate = false;

organization.Models.Add(newModel);
_organizationRepo.SaveChanges();
```

Note that `organization.Models`is read from the repository beforehand.

My problem is that instead of creating a dublicate record with the new name and no tempalte flag, the template record is altered.

Criteria:

- I want to create a new record which is a copy of an existing record
- I want to alter the new record
- I do NOT want to alter the existing record

I would assume Entity Framework would interpret the `organization.Models.Add(newModel)` statement as insert new record but it does not.

Comment: try using AsNoTracking as in here http://stackoverflow.com/a/15322430/891715

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to the problem was (as Arie commented on the original question) to use `AsNoTracking()` [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15322430/891715) when finding the template entry.

One catch using this is that this workaround is not meant as

***"read values (template) -> Change as needed -> insert new record"***

but rather a **read-only** operation. This meant that I had to manually **eager load** all references to the template in order to ensure these getting included in the `Add()` operation on the DataContext.

I did this by loading properties into a variable before saving the object eg.

```
var modelFromTemplate = organization.Models.FirstOrDefault(m => m.IsTemplate == true);
var eagerLoadParams = modelFromTemplate.Parameters.ToList();

//Change stuff as needed on the template here
modelFromTemplate.Name = "Something New";
modelFromTemplate.IsTemplate = false;

//Save the new model
_modelRepo.Add(modelFromTemplate);
_modelRepo.SaveChanges();
```