# object's key information and cannot be modified

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to duplicate currentAppointment to appointment. My issue is that currentAppointment has a GUID. When I try to create a new duplicate appointment I get the following error. **'The property 'AppID' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified. '**.

This completely makes sense why I am getting this error and I know I can get around it by going field by field down and match them up (32 fields) but I would like to know if there is a way to give 'appointment' a new guid without going field by field.

```
        Appointment currentAppointment = db.Appointments.Find(id);

        Appointment appointment = currentAppointment;

        appointment.AppID = Guid.NewGuid(); (where I get the error since I already have a guid from currentAppointment but would like appointment to have a new one.)
        appointment.AgentID = 1;
        appointment.StatusID = 13;
        db.Appointments.Add(appointment);
```

Comment: You need to read about [reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types) (and probably [value types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/value-types) too). You get the error because `appointment` is just a pointer to the same object represented by `currentAppointment`, if you change one you change the other. What is `db`? Is it Entity Framework or something else?

Comment: Entity Framework

Comment: You could consider using `AsNoTracking` to accomplish this, perhaps.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15308747/entity-framework-5-deep-copy-clone-of-an-entity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So as mentioned in my comment you should read about [Reference Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types) vs [Value Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/value-types) to understand why you get this error.

In short when you say `Appointment appointment = currentAppointment;` you're kind of creating a link from `appointment` to the same object that `currentAppointment` represents. When you change a property on either, it will change on the other.

Entity Framework has a way to map one class onto another like this:

```
// Get current Appointment
var currentAppointment = db.Appointments.Find(id);

// Make a brand new Appointment
var appointment = new Appointment();

// Map one to the other
db.Entry(currentAppointment).CurrentValues.SetValues(appointment);

// Change the ID
appointment.AppID = Guid.NewGuid();

// Add to database
db.Appointments.Add(appointment);

// Whatever else happens

// Save
db.SaveChanges();
```

You may want to do some work to avoid collision as there's a chance that the GUID for the appointment could already exist.

Personally I'd recommend having the database column for `AppId` set as an `identifier` that generates the GUID itself. Then your object in C# just has a `null` ID when added, the rest is done at the database level.

Answer (score 0):

With that error, I think your AppID, is your primary Key. So if this is a primary key, your Guid.NewGuid(); can return a value wich already exist in database. So you can save that in a variable and validade if exist any appointment with that key, if not add, if exist, you car generate another.

Answer (score 0):

To create new objects in a loop, you can use code like this:

```
foreach (Array element in empList)
{
  objEmp= new Employee(); // this is the line i wrote to repair error
  objEmp.Name= "EmpName";
  objEmp.Mobile= "012345678942";
  int nextID=getnextIDFunction();
  objEmp.PKID = nextVisitParamID;
  bllEmp.Save(objEmp);
}
```

The important part here is that you create a **new Object** each time.
The values that you add to the new Object would retrieved from the old.