# How to copy a row with his data linked in other tables (related ) and insert them as a new records - Linq C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, ef-code-first

How to copy a row with his data linked in other tables (related ) and insert them as a new records in All Tables, with :

ASP.NET MVC / C# / Linq (Method syntax) / Entity Framework Code-First

**For Example :**

I have these tables =>

[image]

I want to copy the last line of the "Customer" table and add it in a new line of the database with a new ID, and at the same time copy all orders related in the table "Order" and duplicate them with "CustoemerID" of the new "Customer" with new ID's , and at the same time copy all orders lines in table  "OrderLine" and duplicate them with the new "OrderID"

How to do it ?

Is there a brief code for doing this?

[image]

> The blue color is the last row in the database, and the green color is
>   the result of the code what i'm looking for, a duplicate copy of the
>   customer and his related data

**Primary keys : CustomerID & OrderID & OrderLineID = AUTO INCREMENT Field**

Comment: Look here if this help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15308747/entity-framework-5-deep-copy-clone-of-an-entity/15322430#15322430

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of 2 solutions for this question

1. Using Sql query
2. Using EF code first you can create a clone method inside your Customer class.

> ```
>   CREATE TABLE #Customer (
>   CustomerId INT Identity(1, 1)
>   ,Name NVARCHAR(100)
>   ,Address1 NVARCHAR(100)
>   ,Address2 NVARCHAR(100)
>   ,Address3 NVARCHAR(100)
>   )
>
> INSERT INTO #Customer
> VALUES (
>   'N2'
>   ,'A11'
>   ,'A22'
>   ,'A33'
>   )
>
> INSERT INTO #Customer
> SELECT Name
>   ,Address1
>   ,Address2
>   ,Address3
> FROM #Customer
> GROUP BY Name
>   ,Address1
>   ,Address2
>   ,Address3
> HAVING Count(*) BETWEEN 0
>       AND 1
> ```

**Using Clone method**

```
   public class Customer
    {
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address1 { get; set; }
        public string Address2 { get; set; }
        public string Address3 { get; set; }


        public Customer Clone()
        {
            // where the reference is not detached
            var employee1 = new Customer
            {
                Name = Name,
                Address1 = Address1,
                Address2 = Address2,
                Address3 = Address3
            };

            // with reference detached
            var serialisedData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
            var employee2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Employee>(serialisedData);

            //  return employee1 or employee2;
            return employee1;

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps you:

```
INSERT INTO customer (ID, Name, Address1, Address2, Address3) 
    SELECT 
        3, Name, Address1, Address2, Address3 
    FROM
        customer 
    WHERE
       ID = 2;

INSERT INTO Order (CustomerId, TotalAmount) 
    SELECT CustomerId, TotalAmount 
    FROM Order 
    WHERE CustomerID = 3;

INSERT INTO OrderLine (OrderId, ProductId, Quantity) 
    SELECT ol.OrderId, ol.ProductId, ol.Quantity 
    FROM OrderLine ol 
    WHERE ol.OrderId IN (SELECT o2.OrderId 
                         FROM Order o2 
                         WHERE o2.CustomerID = 3);
```

Comment: For SQL Server - this will definitely **FAIL** - since `Order` is a reserved T-SQL keyword, and if you use it as a table name, you **MUST** put it in square brackets - `[Order]` ....

Comment: In LINQ please , I think you didn't understand my question well, please read it again

Comment: Thanks Marc, yes i agree. Forgot to wrap reserve keyword within square bracket.

Comment: Mazilia, i missed the point that you are looking LINQ query but it wouldn't be difficult to translate above logic to LINQ?